# about jquery bind unbind

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

why this does't work? and how can I fixed it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
            $("button").unbind("click");
            $("div").show().fadeOut("slow",function(){
                $("button").bind("click");
            });
            })
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        div{width:600px;height:600px;display:none;background:red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button>test</button>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've been a user of SO for 1 year, and still no code formatting??

Comment: What is not working? Is there any error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't specifying *what* to bind the `click` event to with `$("button").bind("click");` (it doesn't make any assumptions there, it just silently binds nothing).  You can do this with a named function you store though, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function clickHandler() { 
    $("button").unbind("click");
    $("div").show().fadeOut("slow",function() {
      $("button").bind("click", clickHandler);
      //or: $("button").click(clickHandler);
    });
  }
  $("button").click(clickHandler);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Btu82/). In your case though, it's easier to just check if the `<div>` is hidden, and don't un/re-bind anything, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function () { 
    $("div:hidden").show().fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Btu82/1/).